# read() system call

Tags: fuse

While using fuse to change read() in my filesystem, I happened to notice that read() was called before the other read() finished. Is there anyway to sequentialize them? If they overlap, the data that I expect from first read() is actually created by the second.
Thanks guys

1. read(path="/location.csv", buf=0x01c16960, size=32768, offset=16384, fi=0x33eb4e40)

   start_read for 1
2. read(path="/location.csv", buf=0x01c1eb60, size=65536, offset=49152, fi=0x346b5e40)

   start_read for 2

   end_read for 1

   end_read for 2

Answer (score 0):

Try running your filesystem with the `-s` (single-threaded) option. If it does the trick, you can force it on by using adding it to your `fuse_args` using `fuse_opt_add_arg`.